# How to select data of same date but previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to select same data of previous year?

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Add sample table data (as text) and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @Thiru you can use `DATEADD`, see my answer.

Comment: thanks. gofr1 ..                            SELECT DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())     if i am using this query i will get only current year (2016) and last year(2015). but in my database i have 2000 to till now.

Comment: You just simply posted some data. Please tell us what would be your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN **SQL Server** use [DATEADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SELECT  a.ARRDate,
        a.SomeData, --Current
        b.SomeData  --Previous
FROM MyTable a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b
    ON DATEADD(year,-1,a.ARRDate) = b.ARRDate
```

Join your table with itself.

Comment: (Last_year_ARR_TODAY) in this column i want data. if i am using this one (select DATEADD(YEAR,-1,ARRDate) from FactARR) date only coming properly but i want the data(particular date what data is there i want that data only.)

Comment: And what is the data you want to be shown? In what column it is stored? I add some example to my answer.

Comment: please see my attachment i clearly mention which date data i want. please check the xls file

Comment: I add a sample, that will show data you have and data from last year for each row of your table, just rename `MyTable` to your actual table name, and same to `SomeDtat` column, just use columns from `a.` and `b.` you need

Comment: Thanks Gofr1. above that query is working fine. but data is not there means i want to put 0 value.but here it's showing NULL value. how can i change this one.

Comment: For fields you need to show `0` instead of `NULL` use `ISNULL(SomeColumn,0) as SomeColumn`